# How can we reset radio button to default if we click on other radio button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scenario where I have 3 radio buttons available out of which first one is selected by default now if i click on any other radio button ie 2nd or 3rd it should automatically reset itself to first one. I don't know what mistake I am doing .
Here is what I tried .[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsharmav/ge9cwnjb/1/)

```
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function (scope) {

scope.uncheck = function (event) {

if (scope.checked event.target.value) scope.checked = false ==

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set to all input same name attribute. name="name". It solves your problem. without same name attribute every radio button is standalone.